# Activity not finishing when putExtra is called

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have a piece of Android code where I am calling an activity to take a picture and would like the picture as a result.

```
Intent data = new Intent();
data.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
data.putExtra("Image", b);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);

finish();
```

Problem is that when I call `finish()`, the

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
```

of my main activity is not getting called.

and for reference this is how I am starting the result activity.

```
public void startPictureView(View v)
{
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), CameraActivity.class);

    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}
```

only problem I could think is that `startPictureView` is getting called on a button press from a fragment and there could be a small scope/parent issue, however I have tried putting `onActivityResult` in my fragment code and it did nothing.

Comment: can you try removing `data.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`?

Comment: Tried, it changes nothing.

Comment: mostly the activity's is called first. but do you hit backkey or anything? and also do you have any launchmode specifications for that activity?

Comment: My activity structure is something like 


`Activity A --(startActivityForResult)--> Activity B
then in Activity B the picture is taken and returned like
Activity B --(Put data and finish())--> Activity A`


Where Activity A is my main activity and nothing is before it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are opening an intent to capture an image,why not use 
`Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);`
`startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST);`
And why are you receiving a view in your *startPictureView()* method?

Comment: I have switched to this method. I was originally intending on using my own camera activity but I will add this another day..

Comment: don't forget to define the use of the phone's hardware in the manifest